# Pandas: Reshape and combine data

Tags: python, pandas, visualization

I have three data from CSV file. I want to re-arrange and combine them into one data frame.

```
print (df1)
Year       UK       Australia       US
1960      25870         31400     39810
1970      26810         32511     38920
1980      22210         33633     39820

print (df2)
Country        1970      1980
UK              76        71
US              77        81
Australia       81        89

print (df3)
Year        UK       Australia       US
1960       700         1200         1300
1970       900         800         1000
1980       500         1000         1100
```

I want the final result to look something like the one below.

```
Country     Year    Life Expectancy     GDP     Population   
UK          1970         76             900       26810
UK          1980         71             500       22210
US          1970         77            1000       38920
UK          1980         77            1100       39820
Australia   1970         81            800        32511
Australia   1980         89            1000       33633
```

Comment: There ain't no free lunches.. What have you tried to solve the problem? Show the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and if necessary chnage order of `MultiIndex` levels by [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html), last join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df11 = (df1.set_index('Year')
            .stack()
            .rename_axis((['Year','Country']))
            .rename('Population')
            .swaplevel(1,0))

df21 = (df2.set_index('Country')
           .rename(columns=int)
           .stack()
           .rename_axis((['Country','Year']))
           .rename('Life Expectancy'))
df31 = (df3.set_index('Year')
           .stack()
           .rename_axis((['Year','Country']))
           .rename('GDP')
           .swaplevel(1,0))
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df11, df21, df31], axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
     Country  Year  Population  Life Expectancy   GDP
0  Australia  1960       31400              NaN  1200
1  Australia  1970       32511             81.0   800
2  Australia  1980       33633             89.0  1000
3         UK  1960       25870              NaN   700
4         UK  1970       26810             76.0   900
5         UK  1980       22210             71.0   500
6         US  1960       39810              NaN  1300
7         US  1970       38920             77.0  1000
8         US  1980       39820             81.0  1100
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pd.melt() and pd.merge()

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Year':[1960,1970,1980],
                        'UK':[ 25870,26810,22210],
                        "Australia":[31400,32511,33633],
                        "US":[39810,38920,39820]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={"Country":["UK","US","Australia"],
                        "1970":[76,77,81],
                        "1980":[71,81,89]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Year':[1960,1970,1980],
                        'UK':[ 700,900,500],
                        "Australia":[1200,800,1000],
                        "US":[1300,1000,1100]})
```

```
population = df1.melt(id_vars=['Year'], 
              value_vars=['UK', 'Australia', 'US'],
              var_name='Country', value_name='population')

gdp = df3.melt(id_vars=['Year'], 
              value_vars=['UK', 'Australia', 'US'],
              var_name='Country', value_name='gdp')

expectancy = df2.melt(id_vars=['Country'], 
              value_vars=['1970','1980'],
              var_name='Year', value_name='life_expectancy')

res = pd.merge(population,gdp,on=['Country','Year'],how='outer')
res['Year'] = res['Year'].astype(str)
expectancy['Year'] =expectancy['Year'].astype(str)

final_res = pd.merge(res,expectancy,on=['Year','Country'],how='outer')
```

```
    Year    Country population  gdp life_expectancy
0   1960    UK          25870   700   NaN
1   1970    UK          26810   900  76.0
2   1980    UK          22210   500   71.0
3   1960    Australia   31400   1200   NaN
4   1970    Australia   32511   800    81.0
5   1980    Australia   33633   1000    89.0
6   1960    US          39810   1300    NaN
7   1970    US         38920    1000    77.0
8   1980    US           39820  1100    81.0
```